# My footer is going on top of my content and not staying at the bottom

Tags: html, css

So recently I was building a website and testing some javascript inside of the website (slideshow and live time) but the most irritating part of this website is that I can't seem to make it responsive on multiple pages. I've been using @media and adjusting the website but recently my footer is not staying at the bottom and if I apply any online tips into my website it makes the footer sit on top of my content...

I am not the best web designer and I'm looking for more tips on how to construct this website if anyone is willing to give more tips.

Example:

[image]

HTML: http://pastebin.com/MaFpj9DC

CSS: http://pastebin.com/fAAAgyF3

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `#footer{position:fixed;}` instead of `#footer{position:absolute;}` ;-)

Comment: Please see my new answer. You can delete your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, use the following code:

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
}
```

The fixed-value will will place the element relative to the screen's viewport and doesn't move when scrolled.